# Remove terms with NA coefficients from lm model with interactions

Tags: r, regression

I'm training a model using lm with interactions by

```
fit <- lm(Y ~ .^2, data)
```

Some of the interaction terms have "NA" as their coefficient, indicating I suppose that not all terms are independent. 
How can I automatically remove terms with "NA" as coefficients from fit?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd rather say that you don't have anough observations for all interactions. To exclude any coefficient from a regression type: `fit2 <- lm(Y ~ .^2 - x1:x2, data)` this would exclude the interaction betweet x1 and x2 (while their main effects are still fitted).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.
Could you please explain why you believe that I have too few observations? I'm new to this.

Comment: I just guessed it because it is a frequent problem. With the `.^2`, you fit all pairwise interactions between all variables in the dataset. If you have, say, 10 continuous variables in your dataset, you fit 10 main effects plus ${10 \choose 2} = 45$ interactions. With categorical variables even more! Maybe you could describe your data in the question and provide us the model output. From the information you've given here, it is still difficult to say what the problem actually is.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot share the data as it is confidential. 
You mentioned that I can remove interaction using fit2 <- lm(Y ~ .^2 - x1:x2, data). That is fine, but is it possible to remove all those with "NA" coefficients automatically?

Comment: remove NA values from dataset: `newdata <- na.omit(mydata)`

Comment: @pgericson: The default for `lm` is to do an `na.omit`. The NA's that dafeda is getting for coefficients are due to other things, as COOLSerdash notes.

Comment: @dafeda: It sounds like you're doing a shotgun approach which is rarely a good idea. As COOLSerdash points out, you could have a lot of possible interactions. And your approach is basically a fishing expedition that will probably find "significant" interactions that aren't actually significant. There are other techniques, such as `lasso` which would be a better idea if you insist on fishing. But having some motivated idea about what interactions make sense or are expected is probably the best approach.

Comment: @Wayne: You are absolutely right that I'm on a fishing expedition. I have to a certain extent an idea of which interactions make sense, and will of course use this domain specific knowledge in the final model. Right now, I'm just playing with R. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @dafeda: I may be confused, but you might want to look at the `hierNet` package.